# Масштабирование изображения

Tags: изображения, java, swing

Добрый день. Хочу реализовать инструмент по типу лупы в пэинте. есть BufferedImage, нужно его масштабировать либо в +, либо в -. Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Я смотрю проверить этот ответ только завтра. Завтра же и поставлю галочку, если заработает. Сегодна никак не смогу проверить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29).